# Is there a hotkey to select all the text I've typed in a unix command?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, unix, terminal

In some shell such as terminal on Mac OS X, I want to select all the text I've typed in the command line. For example, I've typed this in the command line and have yet to hit enter. I want to do a select all (such as ctrl A or apple A) so that I can cut or copy this command (ctrl X/C or apple X/C).

```
$ grep -r "test" .
```

Is there a way to do this without having to use the mouse and actually selecting all of the command? This would make life easier for when I need to copy a unix command to send to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how it works on my OSX laptop.

```
bash$ echo "this is a command I haven't run yet"             # press Ctrl-u here
bash$                                                        # blank line
bash$ pbcopy <<<                                             # now I press Ctrl-y
bash$ pbcopy <<< echo "this is a command I haven't run yet"  # press Enter
bash$
```

From here, the command is in the clipboard and I haven't used the mouse or set up any keyboard shortcuts.  This will work with the standard bash, so you don't need to set up MacPorts either.

Comment: I found, at least on OS X 10.9, that simply CTRL-u/CTRL-y work just fine all by themselves.  I'm also using iTerm...  Thanks for the tip. +1

Answer (score 0):

Your terminal might provide something like that. Applications like `screen` and `tmux` also sometimes provide things like that (though generally only for use in the shell session I think and not into the system clipboard). There's a layering problem with just about anything else doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a terminal shortcut to select all of the text. One alternative may be to use the pbcopy command to copy the last command into the system pasteboard.

```
fc -ln -1 | pbcopy
```

You can then use Command-V to paste anywhere else on your computer. It's probably not faster than using your mouse, but if you need to do it a lot, you could create an alias.

Answer (score 0):

Not with the OS X default bash. (It is only 3.2).

But if you install bash 4.0+ (i'm recommendind using [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org)) you can use the next feature:

> **bind**
>
> -x keyseq:shell-command
>
> Cause shell-command to be executed whenever keyseq is entered.
> When shell-command is executed, the shell sets the READLINE_LINE
> variable to the contents of the Readline line buffer and the
> READLINE_POINT variable to the current location of the insertion
> point. If the executed command changes the value of READLINE_LINE or
> READLINE_POINT, those new values will be reflected in the editing
> state.

So, for example you can bind the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> sequence, (press CTRL-X and after an simple "c") to the `pbcopy` with the next `bind` command:

```
bind -x '"\C-xc":pbcopy <<<"$READLINE_LINE"'
```

Now, anything you typed into bash, after pressing "CTRL-X c" will be copied into the clipboard.

If you're not like the sequence, you can also set the sequince in the Terminal.app -> Preferences -> Settings -> Keyboard as in the next screeenshot

[image]

where I binded the "CTRL-X c" `\030c` to the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>LEFT_ARROW</kbd>, so now i have both binding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use history file to do that. Make your bash to write all commands to history file immediately, as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/preserve-bash-history-in-multiple-terminal-windows)

Then make a keybinding to run script `tail ~/.bash_history -n 1 | pbcopy`. Or you can integrate this script directly to PROMPT_COMMAND variable as described in link.

Not tested:
`PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r; tail ~/.bash_history -n 1 | pbcopy; $PROMPT_COMMAND"`